# What is the first of the two type parameters of the function passed to a `collect` method in Scala?

Tags: scala, generics

Why does the [method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/#scala.collection.immutable.List)

```
def collect[B](pf: PartialFunction[A, B]): List[B]
```

declared with the method only being dependent on the type `B` (`collect[B]`)?

The signature shows this method depends on both `A` and `B`.

Comment: Because the type parameter `A` is a type parameter of the class `List` that contains the method instead of of the method itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on `A` but `A` is already determined by the Type you created the list of, because `collect` is a function of the class `List[A]`.

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked it.